# Vue.js: To Get Environment Variables in js File

Tags: vue.js

I have created .env file to set environment variables as shown below:

[image]

Inside which I have given below mentioned code.

```
VUE_APP_BASEURL="https://qa-apps-nodejs.Dtech.com:9000/"
PORT=8080
```

I have written below code in my js file and executed `npm install dotenv`:

```
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_BASEURL);
```

With the above code, I need to get `https://qa-apps-nodejs.Dtech.com:9000/` in console. But instead I'm getting:

> undefined

Comment: are you using vue-cli ?

Comment: Yes. Vue CLI v4.1.2

Comment: can you try solutions [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1610). May be you can try restarting your server.

Comment: It worked now. I just restart the server. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just restart your server as newly created env variables are not available only after hot-reload you have to rebuild your application (restart your server). For reference you can look [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1610)

Answer (score 1):

No need to install "dotenv" simply place `.env` file in the root of your project (at the same level of your `package.json` file) and Vue CLI will handle the reset. Side note; as of Vue CLI 3 only variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be loaded. make sure also to rerun `npm run serve` again to restart your server.

for more details: [visit docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes)